# Undefined property: stdClass::$categoria

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, querybuilder

Estoy comenzando a desarrollar en Laravel 7. Tengo dos modelos relacionados 'Categorias' y 'Subcategorias' por el campo categoria_id. En la vista 'index' de 'subcategoria' se muestra una tabla con todas las subcategorias y utilizando la relación belongsTo de Eloquent accedo al nombre de la categoria para mostrarlo en lugar del id.

El problema surge en el buscador, se compone de un combo donde puedo elegir entre filtrar por categoria o nombre de subcategoria y un campo vacío para introducir el texto a buscar. La idea es hacer un join si se busca por categoria (ya que en la tabla subcategoria solo tengo el id y no el nombre) y comparar el texto buscado con el nombre de la categoria.

Si la búsqueda la realizo por 'nombre de subcategoria' funciona perfectamente, pero cuando es por 'categoria' explota. Por lo poco que entiendo se debe a que al hacer la consulta con query builder el resultado es un array que se pasa a la vista, y en esta se pierde la propiedad 'categoria' con la que accedia al nombre de la misma al consultar con eloquent. Hay forma de convertir el query builder a eloquent? o existe una forma de hacer ese join sin query builder?

Estos son mis codigos:

```
//Controlador Subcategoria

public function index(Request $request) {

        $buscar = $request->get('buscarpor');
        $tipo = $request->get('tipo');

        $subcategoria = Subcategoria::buscarpor($tipo, $buscar)->paginate(5);
        return view('subcategoria.index', compact('subcategoria'));
    }

//Modelo SubCategoria

    public function categoria() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Categoria', 'categoria_id');
    }

    public function scopeBuscarpor($query, $tipo, $buscar) {
        if (($tipo) && ($buscar)) {

            if ($tipo == 'categoria_id') {

                $query = DB::table('categorias')
                    ->join('subcategorias', 'subcategorias.categoria_id', '=', 'categorias.id')
                    ->where('categorias.nombre', 'like', "%$buscar%");

                return $query; //encuentra los resultados, pero devuelve un error en la vista
                //al querer acceder a la propiedad categoria del objeto $subategoria
                //armado por eloquent.

            } else {
                return $query->where($tipo, 'like', "%$buscar%");
            }
        }
    }

//Tabla del index
@foreach($subcategoria as $subcategoriaitem)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $subcategoriaitem->id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $subcategoriaitem->categoria->nombre }}</td> //aca se presenta el error
            <td>{{ $subcategoriaitem->nombre }}</td>
            ...
        </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

En efecto si pasas por query builder te va a quitar la funcionabilidad de `$subcategoriaitem->categoria->nombre` ya que estas generando un arreglo de tipo raw, si tu modelo y la relación es correcta con esto deberia funcionar:

```
$search = Categoria::where("nombre",$busqueda)->subcategoria;
```

Puedes leer mas de esto en [Eloquent: Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)